# Get device id android

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

How can I change user id (mail) with device id?

I tried:

```
LinearLayout useridPanel = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    useridPanel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    useridPanel
            .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // input userid label
    tv = new TextView(getContext());
    tv.setText(Strings.input_userid_label.get());
    useridPanel.addView(tv);

    // input userid field
    wdp = 240;
    widthPx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, wdp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
    // widthPx=LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    et = new EditText(getContext());
    et.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(widthPx, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS);

    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            sync();
        }
    });
    this.inputUseridField = et;
    useridPanel.addView(et);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? We'd need a bit more information to be able to help.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please rephrase it and tell us what's happening in your program, and what you want to happen instead.